# Improve Python Code

Tags: python, keyboard, hid

I am not a good coder so I hope you can help me out with this one. Please look at my code. I use this code to convert characters to code which is send over to a computer. This code is interpeted as HID keyboard code. I have 2 questions:

1) When code is executed, double signs like "AAA" or "111" are reduced to 1? So "A" and "1" while the preview looks ok?

2) How can I improve this code so I can also send special keystrokes. Now every character is processed seperatly. The dictionary states "TAB" for a tab sign and "DEL" for the delete key. But if everything is matched by character the whole word can never be found and thus the correct code cannot be send.

I hope you are willing to help me improve this code.

Thank you!

```
#!/usr/bin/python

"""
HID Keyboard Mapper
Version: 1.0
By: Jarno Baselier
Date: 2018
URL: www.jarnobaselier.nl
"""

#Imports

#Program variables
LIST    = 1     #If LIST is 1 than complete keymap code is shown on screen
EXECUTE    = 1     #If EXECUTE is 1 than complete keymap code is send to the HID device and executed

#Variables
NULL_CHAR = chr(0)

#Functions
#Create write_report function to write HID codes to the HID Keyboard
def write_report(report):
    with open('/dev/hidg0', 'rb+') as fd:
        fd.write(report.encode())

#Dictionary
values = {
'a':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(4)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'b':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(5)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'c':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(6)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'd':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(7)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'e':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(8)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'f':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(9)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'g':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(10)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'h':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(11)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'i':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(12)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'j':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(13)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'k':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(14)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'l':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(15)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'm':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(16)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'n':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(17)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'o':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(18)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'p':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(19)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'q':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(20)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'r':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(21)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
's':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(22)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
't':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(23)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'u':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(24)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'v':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(25)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'w':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(26)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'x':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(27)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'y':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(28)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'z':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(29)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'A':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(4)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'B':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(5)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'C':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(6)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'D':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(7)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'E':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(8)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'F':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(9)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'G':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(10)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'H':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(11)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'I':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(12)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'J':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(13)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'K':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(14)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'L':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(15)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'M':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(16)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'N':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(17)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'O':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(18)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'P':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(19)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'Q':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(20)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'R':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(21)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'S':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(22)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'T':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(23)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'U':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(24)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'V':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(25)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'W':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(26)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'X':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(27)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'Y':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(28)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'Z':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(29)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'1':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(30)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'2':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(31)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'3':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(32)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'4':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(33)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'5':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(34)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'6':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(35)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'7':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(36)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'8':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(37)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'9':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(38)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'0':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(39)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'!':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(30)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'@':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(31)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'#':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(32)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'$':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(33)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'%':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(34)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'^':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(35)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'&':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(36)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'*':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(37)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'(':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(38)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
')':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(39)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'ENTER':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(40)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'ESC':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(41)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'BACKSPACE':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(42)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'TAB':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(43)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'SPATIE':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(44)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'-':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(45)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'=':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(46)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'{':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(47)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'}':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(48)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'\\':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(49)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'~':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(50)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
';':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(51)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(52)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'`':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(53)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
',':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(54)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'.':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(55)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'/':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(56)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'_':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(45)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'+':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(46)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'[':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(47)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
']':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(48)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'|':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(49)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'0':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(50)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
':':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(51)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'"':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(52)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'~':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(53)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'<':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(54)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'>':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(55)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'?':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(56)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'CAPSLOCK':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(57)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'F1':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(58)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'F2':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(59)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'F3':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(60)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'F4':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(61)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'F5':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(62)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'F6':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(63)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'F7':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(64)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'F8':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(65)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'F9':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(66)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'F10':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(67)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'F11':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(68)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'F12':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(69)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'PRINT SCREEN':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(70)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'SCROLL LOCK':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(71)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'PAUSE':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(72)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'INSERT':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(73)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'HOME':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(74)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'PAGEUP':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(75)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'DELETE':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(76)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'END':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(77)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'PAGEDOWN':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(78)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'}':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(79)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'{':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(80)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
']':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(79)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'[':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(80)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'DOWN':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(81)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'UP':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(82)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'NUM LOCK':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(83)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'Keypad SLASH (/)':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(84)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'Keypad ASTERISK (*)':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(85)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'Keypad MINUS (-)':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(86)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'Keypad PLUS (+)':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(87)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'Keypad ENTER':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(88)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'Keypad 1':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(89)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'Keypad 2':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(90)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'Keypad 3':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(91)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'Keypad 4':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(92)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'Keypad END':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(89)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'Keypad DOWN':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(90)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'Keypad PAGEDOWN':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(91)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'Keypad LEFT':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(92)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'Keypad 5':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(93)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'Keypad 6':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(94)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'Keypad 7':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(95)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'Keypad 8':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(96)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'Keypad 9':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(97)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'Keypad 0':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(98)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'Keypad DOT (.)':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(99)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'Non-US Slash \\':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(100)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'Keypad RIGHT':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(94)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'Keypad HOME':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(95)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'Keypad UP':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(96)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'Keypad PAGEUP':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(97)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'Keypad INSERT':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(98)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'Keypad DEL':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(99)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'Non-US Slash |':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(100)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'COMPOSE / APPLICATION':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(101)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'POWER':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(102)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'Keypad EQUAL (=)':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(103)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'F13':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(104)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'F14':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(105)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'F15':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(106)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'F16':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(107)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'F17':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(108)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'F18':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(109)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'F19':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(110)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'F20':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(111)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'F21':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(112)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'F22':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(113)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'F23':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(114)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'F24':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(115)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'EXECUTE':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(116)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'HELP':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(117)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'MENU':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(118)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'SELECT':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(119)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'STOP':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(120)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'AGAIN':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(121)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'UNCO':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(122)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'CUT':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(123)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'COPY':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(124)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'PASTE':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(125)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'FIND':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(126)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'MUTE':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(127)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'VOLUME UP':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(128)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'VOLUME DOWN':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(129)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'CTRL + ALT + DEL':'write_report(chr(5)+NULL_CHAR+chr(76)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'CTRL + w':'write_report(chr(1)+NULL_CHAR+chr(26)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'WIN + TAB':'write_report(chr(8)+NULL_CHAR+chr(43)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'ALT + TAB':'write_report(chr(4)+NULL_CHAR+chr(43)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'CTRL + F':'write_report(chr(1)+NULL_CHAR+chr(9)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
'CTRL + ALT +     ARROWDOWN':'write_report(chr(5)+NULL_CHAR+chr(81)+NULL_CHAR*5)',
}

user_input = input("Please tell me what you would like to translate: ")

#Create an empty list which we will fill later
translated_list = []

#FOR Loop, loops every letter trough dictionary and saves translation in             translated_list
for letter in user_input:
   if letter in values:
       translated_list.append(values[letter])

#Print the translated command
#The current command removes the comma's and brackets by making the output a string and devides every string by a whiteline
if LIST == 1:
    print ("\n")
    print ("\n")
    print ("This is the translated command:")
    print ("________________________________")
    print("\n".join(translated_list))

#Write keyboard codes to the HID device
if EXECUTE == 1:
    exec("\n".join(translated_list))
    #End with a NULL command to release all keys and avoid a endless string
    write_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)
```

Comment: Code improvement questions are usually asked on Code Review: http://codereview.stackexchange.com - Also see: https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6429

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.

Comment: You need to send a "no keys pressed" (I.e. all nulls) report after every individual keystroke. A report containing "AAA" is the same as a report containing just "A". Each report simply indicates which keys are concurrently pressed. Order is not important within the report, but the sequence of reports *is* important.

Comment: @martineau in this current form this question is off-topic on Code Review, as it asks how to implement new features. Also, the first question indicates that the behaviour is not as intended, which is also off-topic on Code Review. [Please do not vote to close with a custom reason that "it belongs on Code Review". Nothing in the Stack Overflow rules justifies such a custom reason.](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: @Zeta: OK, even though I don't completely agree— rather, just don't really care enough to get into an extended discussion about it.

Comment: martineau & rayryeng - Thank you for the tip. I posted the question on Codereview. 

Zeta - Thank you for your opinion. I also agree with you!

@Aja - Thank you for the suggestion! Did not think about it this way but you are right. Thanks!

Comment: @aja - I am trying to do this but cannot get it to work. Can you tell me how I can automaticly send "write_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)" after each report? Addint them in the dictionary gives an error. And adding them like this also generates an error: exec("write_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)".join(translated_list)). THANKS

Comment: Hello everyone. Thank you for your help. The issue is solved! I have rewritten the code a bit and figured out how to get it working! Thans!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You type:

```
for letter in user_input:
   if letter in values:
       translated_list.append(values[letter])
```

it's not necessary to add the `(values[letter])`

I got the duplicate part of your code fixed by doing:

```
for letter in user_input:
    if letter in values:
        translated_list.append(letter)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I will look at it later today and let you know.

Comment: No problem, don’t be afraid to ask more questions!

Comment: Hello DevOps,

I changed my code with above suggestion but when I do I receive the error:

line 230, in <module>
    if letter in value:
NameError: name 'value' is not defined

Hope you can help me. Thanks!

Comment: Ofcourse! I didn’t type it correctly, try values instead of values! I forgot the S, my bad

Comment: Als je wilt kan ik je ook een keer een snelcursus python geven, ik ben zelf afgestudeerd in Development met een specialisatie in python en kobolt, het is voor mij geen enkel probleem om je de basic denkwijze te leren!

Comment: Hallo @DevOps ! Dat lijkt me wel fantastisch. Ik zou graag beter leren coderen in Python. Hoe gaat zoiets in zijn werk? Zijn hier kosten aan verbonden etc? Lijkt me zeker interessant. M.v.g. Jarno

Comment: Als je me de dingen opschrijft die je wilt leren dan zal ik ze zo goed mogelijk uitleggen, Ik heb toevallig nog een paar leuke beginner codeer opdrachten van mijn school periode opgeslagen. Die zou ik je kunnen sturen met hints naar welke technieken worden gebruikt. Zo ben je "spelenderwijs" aan het leren!

Comment: Hoi @DevOps. Super bedankt voor het aanbod. Is het ook een keer mogelijk om een dag samen te zitten. Op die manier is kennisoverdracht nog fijner. Als je dat niet wilt dan is dat geen enkel probleem. Ik snap ook dat je daar centjes voor vraagt. Ik zou zelf heel graag begrijpen hoe bepaalde opdrachten opgebouwd zijn. Ik snap in de basis wel wat variabele, lijsten, functies e.d. zijn. Maar hoe kun je deze beter gebruiken. Waarom gebruik ik b.v. "translated_list.append(values[letter])"? Ik snap niet dat hier [letter] staat. En wat kan ik nog meer gebruiken om het commando te veranderen?

Comment: Je gebruikt `values[letter]` omdat `letter` een teller is. Je zou dit ook kunnen veranderen voor `for x in values: print(values[x])`. een makkelijk voorbeeld:

 stel je hebt 10 waarden, dan gaat letter telkens van 0 naar 9 tellen. Het is vergelijkbaar met `While x <10: x = x + 1`, dit is eigenlijk wat je doet met `for x in range(10)`

Comment: Een keer samen zitten is natuurlijk altijd mogelijk! Mocht het qua afstand niet uitkomen is een discord/skype gesprek natuurlijk een goed alternatief! Laat maar iets weten dan stuur ik je mijn gegevens!

Comment: Hoi DevOps. Dat lijkt me een prima idee. Discord is wat mij betreft prima. Aankomende week heb ik vakantie. Stuur me s.v.p. je gegevens via mijn website jarnobaselier[dot]nl en dan kom ik er na volgende week graag op terug.

Comment: Hallo DevOps. Is bovenstaande nog gelukt? Ik heb je gegevens nog niet gezien. Mocht je in de gelegenheid zijn om ze me toe te sturen dan zie ik ze uiteraard heel graag. Fijne dag.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your help. The issue is solved! I have rewritten the code a bit and figured out how to get it working! Thanks!

The working code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

"""
HID Keyboard Mapper
Version: 1.0
By: Jarno Baselier
Date: 2018
URL: www.jarnobaselier.nl

Deze HID Keyboard Mapper is speciaal gemaakt om snel toetsenbord keystrokes
om te zetten naar Python en door te zetten naar het HID device.
Stel voor dat je een Raspberry Pi USB poort (zoals op de Zero mogelijk is)
configureerd als HID device en aansluit op een computer dan kun je vanuit
deze Python convertor meteen keystrokes sturen naar de aangesloten computer.
"""

#Imports

#Program variables
LIST    = 1     #If LIST is 1 than complete keymap code is shown on screen
EXECUTE    = 1     #If EXECUTE is 1 than complete keymap code is send to the HID device and executed

#Variables
NULL_CHAR = chr(0)

#Functions
#Create write_report function to write HID codes to the HID Keyboard
def write_report(report):
    with open('/dev/hidg0', 'rb+') as fd:
        fd.write(report.encode())

#Dictionary
values = {
'a':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(4)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)',
'b':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(5)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)',
'c':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(6)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)',
'd':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(7)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)',
'e':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(8)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)',
'f':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(9)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)',
'g':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(10)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)',
'h':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(11)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)',
'i':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(12)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)',
'j':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(13)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)',
'k':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(14)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)',
'l':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(15)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)',
'm':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(16)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)',
'n':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(17)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)',
'o':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(18)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)',
'p':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(19)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)',
'q':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(20)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)',
'r':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(21)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)',
's':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(22)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)',
't':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(23)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)',
'u':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(24)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)',
'v':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(25)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)',
'w':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(26)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)',
'x':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(27)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)',
'y':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(28)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)',
'z':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(29)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)',
'A':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(4)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)',
'B':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(5)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)',
'C':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(6)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)',
'D':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(7)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)',
'E':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(8)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)',
'F':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(9)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)',
'G':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(10)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)',
'H':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(11)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)',
'I':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(12)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)',
'J':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(13)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)',
'K':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(14)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)',
'L':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(15)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)',
'M':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(16)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)',
'N':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(17)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)',
'O':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(18)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)',
'P':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(19)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)',
'Q':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(20)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)',
'R':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(21)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)',
'S':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(22)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)',
'T':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(23)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)',
'U':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(24)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)',
'V':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(25)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)',
'W':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(26)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)',
'X':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(27)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)',
'Y':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(28)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)',
'Z':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(29)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)',
'1':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(30)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)',
'2':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(31)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)',
'3':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(32)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)',
'4':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(33)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)',
'5':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(34)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)',
'6':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(35)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)',
'7':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(36)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)',
'8':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(37)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)',
'9':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(38)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)',
'0':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(39)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)',
'!':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(30)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)',
'@':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(31)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)',
'#':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(32)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)',
'&':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(36)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)',
'*':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(37)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)',
'(':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(38)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)',
')':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(39)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)',
'-':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(45)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)',
'=':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(46)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)',
'{':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(47)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)',
'}':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(48)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)',
'\\':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(49)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)',
';':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(51)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)',
'':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(52)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)',
'`':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(53)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)',
',':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(54)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)',
'.':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(55)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)',
'/':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(56)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)',
'0':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(50)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)',
':':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(51)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)',
'"':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(52)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)',
'<':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(54)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)',
'>':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(55)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)',
'?':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(56)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)',
'}':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(79)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)',
'{':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(80)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)',
']':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(79)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)',
'[':'write_report(chr(2)+NULL_CHAR+chr(80)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)',

#Next Signs are used for different keymappings - change if you want to
'$':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(40)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)', #ENTER
'%':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(41)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)', #ESC
'^':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(42)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)', #BACKSPACE
'~':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(43)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)', #TAB
'_':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(44)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)', #SPATIE
'+':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(70)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)', #PRINT SCREEN
'[':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(76)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)', #DELETE
']':'write_report(chr(5)+NULL_CHAR+chr(76)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)', #CTRL+ALT+DEL
'|':'write_report(NULL_CHAR*2 +chr(81)+NULL_CHAR*5)\nwrite_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)', #DOWN
}

user_input = input("Please tell me what you would like to translate: ")

#Create an empty list which we will fill later
translated_list = []

#FOR Loop, loops every letter trough dictionary and saves translation in             translated_list
for letter in user_input:
   if letter in values:
       translated_list.append(values[letter])

#Print the translated command
#The current command removes the comma's and brackets by making the output a string and devides every string by a whiteline
if LIST == 1:
    print ("\n")
    print ("\n")
    print ("Below is the translated script, ready to copy-paste:")
    print ("____________________________________________________")
    print ("#!/usr/bin/env python3")
    print ("NULL_CHAR = chr(0)")
    print ("")
    print ("def write_report(report):")
    print ("    with open('/dev/hidg0', 'rb+') as fd:")
    print ("        fd.write(report.encode())")
    print ("")
    print("\n".join(translated_list))

#Write keyboard codes to the HID device
if EXECUTE == 1:
    exec ("\n".join(translated_list))
    #End with a NULL command to release all keys and avoid a endless string
    write_report(NULL_CHAR * 8)
```

Answer (score 0):

The DevOps answer brings error, mine should fix the problem.
So you type:

```
for letter in user_input:
   if letter in values:
       translated_list.append(values[letter])
```

I got the duplicate part of your code fixed by adding the release key:

```
for letter in user_input:
   if letter in values:
       translated_list.append(values[letter])
       translated_list.append('write_report(NULL_CHAR*8)')
```

In other words, if you received 'AAA', it would be like pressing keyboard button A, releasing the key, pressing A again, releasing the key again, so they will be no reduction or merging of the same character.